# MySQL order by two random rows then the rest

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query like below, but what I want to do is bring out two records, selected at random that have a type of 3, 4 or 5 first and then bring out the rest as normal (by listings.id in this example).

```
SELECT listings.id, listings.type
FROM listings 
ORDER BY listings.id DESC
```

I hope I have made myself clear, but if you need anymore details please do let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Mark

Comment: See FIELD() and/or UNION

Comment: I can see how it can be done with UNION, but I would rather avoid that method, because the real life query is very complicated and would mean breaking it up. Is there anyway of just using FIELD? I know how to use it to order by certain fields first, but not how to limit the number.

Answer (score 0):

You need a union of 2 queries like the following:

```
SELECT listings.id, listings.type
FROM listings 
WHERE listings.type IN (3,4,5)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT listings.id, listings.type
FROM listings 
ORDER BY listings.id DESC
```